# Change order status in Magento via SQL

Tags: sql, magento

I am having an issue my third party payment gateway have changed a cancelled order status of an order to pending so now I am stuck with a pending order for ever.

I was speaking over the phone with the client he said had a problem with the credit card so I cancelled her order and when the backend received the notice form bank then it changed to pending.

So is there anyway to cancel it again? perhaps via SQL?

Regards,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm running enterprise, and managed to do it with:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = 'processing';  
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state = 'processing', status = 'processing';
```

Somebody had managed to wipe all the order statuses, and that's how I was easily able to get them back. 
Of course, if you wanted to update specific records, you'd add `WHERE entity_id = '12345'` or whatever to the end of the query. 
And always backup the database before you run any queries like the above!

Answer (score 9):

Previous answers are missing the request updating the 'sales_flat_order_grid' table.
If the question is still active the full request is:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = 'canceled' WHERE increment_id = <order_increment_id>;
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state='canceled', status='canceled' WHERE increment_id =<order_increment_id> (or WHERE entity_id = <order_id>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding info to Silas answer: you may need to insert a new status in sale status history.

```
INSERT INTO sales_flat_order_status_history (`parent_id`,`is_customer_notified`,`is_visible_on_front`,`comment`,`status`,`entity_name`,`created_at`) VALUES (YOUR_ORDER_ID,0,0,'',NEW_STATUS_CODE,'order','2014-05-20 11:42:29')
```

Comment: parent id mean what?

Answer (score 0):

What about SQL:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state="canceled", status="canceled" WHERE entity_id = {order id should be here} AND increment_id = {order increment id should be here}
```

In this query you should specify either entity_id or increment_id or both. As you wish.

### WARNING

Make a backup of your database before you do change something. I didn't had any time to analyze the db structure and constraints related to an order.

What about PHP:

Run following PHP script from root folder:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);//id is you order increment id 
OR
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);//id is you order id 
if ($order->getId()) {
    $order->cancel()->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! with the SQL didnt work but doing via PHP was a breeze ;)

Answer (score 0):

please consider that changing the order state/status won't be enough: you should also cancel item(s) and amount information, joining the `sales_flat_order_item`.